# Como passar valor entre Functional Components usando Navigation.navigate

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, mobile

estou tentando passar valores de um Componente Funcional para outro Componente Funcional com navigation.navigate, na primeira tela o valor está lá, posso vê-lo renderizando-o ou no console.log, mas quando tento obtê-lo na segunda tela Eu recebo "undefined".
Oque eu preciso é receber o valor que está no r.id na primeira tela, na segunda tela. Para que eu possa efetuar outras consultas.

Aqui passo o valor para navigation.navigate:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('AuditS',{audit:r.id})} style={styles.button}>
```

Vou postar meu código abaixo, se alguém puder me dar uma ajuda aprecio muito.

First Component:

```
import React, { createElement, useState, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View,TouchableOpacity,Image} from 'react-native';
import AuditButton from './component/AuditButton'
import axios from 'axios' 

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

const [checklists, setChecklists] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
axios.get("http://100.13.16.113:8081/api/checklists", {      
              }).then
              (function (response) {
                setChecklists(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);

              }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);                        
              })
},[]);

return (
<View >
   <Text style={styles.text}> Select an Audit</Text>

  <View style={styles.maincontainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      {checklists.map(r =>(

        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('AuditS',{audit:r.id})} style={styles.button}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/icons8-audit-80.png')} 
            style={styles.Image}>
          </Image>     
      <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>{r.checklisT_DESCRIPTION}{r.id}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity >
        ))}
      </View>
  </View>
    <View style={styles.bottomcontainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('Login')}     
    >
    <Text style = {styles.logout}>LOGOUT</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
</View>

);
};
```

Segundo Componente:

```
import React, { createElement, useState,Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, 
View,TouchableOpacity,Image,ScrollView,Modal,TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {Collapse,CollapseHeader, CollapseBody} from 'accordion-collapse-react-native';
import AuditItem from './component/AuditItem'
import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
import AuditCategory from './component/AuditCategory';



const AuditScreen = ({ audit, navigation}) =>
{
const [modalInfoVisible, setModalInfoVisible] = useState(false);
const [opNumber, setOP] = useState(false);
const [FGINumber, setFGI] = useState(false);
const [checklistitems, setChecklistitems] = useState([]);
const auditId = audit;
console.log(JSON.stringify(auditId));



return ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto:

```
const AuditScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { audit } = route.params;
  console.log(audit);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, pela ajuda, já havia tentado da forma sugerida, mas ela funciona apenas na versão 5.x . Falha minha acabei esquecendo de mencionar que estou utilizando a versão 4.3.9.
 Consegui acessar o valor desta forma na segunda tela:´
`const {audit} = navigation.state.params;`

Dei uma olhada na documentação de como migrar do React Navigation 4.x para 5.x

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta é um pouco antiga, não sei como estava o suporte a alguns hooks na época, mas hoje eu recomendo utilizar `useNavigation` e `useRoute` para quem tiver o mesmo problema.

First Component:

```js
...

import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';


const HomeScreen = () => {

const navigation = useNavigation();


    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('AuditS',{audit:r.id})} 
        style={styles.button}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/icons8-audit-80.png')} 
            style={styles.Image}>
          </Image>     
          <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>{r.checklisT_DESCRIPTION}{r.id}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
...
```

Second Component:

```js
...

import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';


const AuditScreen = () => {

const route = useRoute();
const audit = route.params.audit;
console.log(audit);

...
```

Usei recentemente dessa mesma forma e tá funcionando perfeitamente, caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida ainda.